# F# functional interface

Tags: f#

Given the functions:

```
let doTrue = fun(x) -> true
let doFalse = fun(x) -> false
```

I want to reuse the function signature so that i can get

```
let myFunDefinition = ??? // <-- this is the function signature that i am trying to reuse
let doTrue = myFunDefinition -> true // <-- now i don't have to type fun(x) any more
let doFalse = myFunDefinition -> false
```

Is it possible to define for reuse a function signature?

Comment: I don't understand the way that you're using the word "signature".  Additionally, your first example doesn't even compile (`true` and `false` should be lowercase, and you need `else` blocks if you have non-`unit` values in your `if` branches).  Could you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: I think he's asking for a function that takes a generic type as an argument but, as usual, it's hard to tell what he's asking.

Comment: @kvb reading it, I think he's looking for a higher order function that returns a function that evaluates to true or false but that's just a guess.

Comment: I had a hard time wording this. But basically i want to reuse the signature of a function so that i don't have to keep defining it. The x variable really is there just so that i have a signature.

Comment: i made some edits to the question that i hope will help

Comment: -1 I have no idea what you're asking for here. You are misusing the term "function signature".

Comment: you'll come across the term eventually when you start studying program languages. here's a reference for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even after the edits, your question doesn't really make sense to me.  First of all, the *signature* of `doTrue` and `doFalse` is `'a -> bool` as you have written them, but I don't think that this is really relevant to your question because I don't see what it would mean to "reuse" the signature.  Instead, it seems like you want some form of text macro that will allow you to type `myFunDefinition` and have that replaced by the text `fun (x)`.  Aside from the fact that your replacement text is longer than the original text, here are a few thoughts:

- F# doesn't have text replacement macros, so if that's the exact feature you want, you're out of luck.
- If you want to save typing, you could at least use the more concise formulation `let doTrue x = ...` instead of `let doTrue = fun x -> ...`
- If you actually want `doTrue` and `doFalse` to be the *application* of some other function to `true` and `false`, then that is easy:

  ```
  let myFunDefinition b = {{some function of b}}
  let doTrue = myFunDefinition true
  let doFalse = myFunDefinition false
  ```

  In this case, perhaps this is what you're looking for:

  ```
  let myFunDefinition b _ = b
  ...
  ```

  (?)  This just ignores the second argument (which becomes the first argument of `doTrue` and `doFalse` because they partially apply `myFunDefinition` to the first arguments of `true` or `false`, respectively).
- If you instead want some other sort of abstraction, then the other answers make some reasonable guesses as to what that might mean.  In general, you will get more helpful answers if you spend more time articulating your question so that it clearly communicates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly as the test `x = 1` is different from `x = 3` in your example while `myFunDefinition` appears to be the same in your second block.

Assuming you just want to do something different if some predicate is true or is false (say `x = 1`), I would write the following OCaml code (you may have to adapt the syntax slightly).

```
let doIfPredicate p a deflt = if p then a else deflt
let predicate x = (x = 1)
let doTrue x = doIfPredicate (predicate x) true false
let doFalse x = doIfPredicate (not (predicate x)) false true
let doTrue2 x = doIfPredicate (predicate x) (print_string "true") ()
```

Comment: One small thing @Halladba--_default_ is a keyword in F#.

Comment: i'm trying to actually reuse the function definition. the logic isn't important and so i've edited it out of the question.

Comment: I don't see how my answer or BUEPIXY's answer are not reusing the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

```
let myFunDefinition funcP ret =
  fun (x) -> if funcP x then ret else not ret
let doTrue = myFunDefinition ((=) 1) true
let doFalse = myFunDefinition ((=) 3) false
```

Comment: i'm trying to actually reuse the function definition. the logic isn't important and so i've edited it out of the question.